# Variables are being reset to '1' in modal window

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

Yesterday I installed twitter bootstrap to upgrade my web app project. Everything is going well until I hit a problem with a modal window.

I followed the bootstrap documentation on setting up a button that triggers (unhides) a modal window.

My modal window pulls up a form with 3 visible fields and a few hidden fields which gets it's values from mysql select query.

For some reason two of my values ($mID and $selID) keep getting reset to '1'.
The $fixtureID seems to come through OK however it is defined in a parent php file which this current page is included into.

Am I not able to pass variables to a form/div that is hidden?

Here is my code.

```
<div class="panel-body" id="fxmkbox<?= $fixtureID ?>">

<?php

$mksql = "SELECT * FROM `markets` WHERE sportID = 2";
$mkresult = mysql_query($mksql);

while ($mk = mysql_fetch_assoc($mkresult)) {
    $mID = $mk['ID'];
    $mkname = $mk['name'];
    ?>
    <div class="fmbox">
    <div class="fmhead"><?= $mkname ?></div>
    <div class="fmrow">
    <?php
    $selsql = "SELECT * FROM `selection` WHERE marketID = $mID";
    $selresult = mysql_query($selsql);

    while ($sel = mysql_fetch_assoc($selresult)) {
    $selID = $sel['ID'];
    $selname = $sel['name'];
    ?>
    <div class="col-md-3">
    <div class="fmcell"><?= $selname ?></div>
    <div class="fmcell">

<!-- Button trigger modal -->
<button class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">
                          <?php $odds = show_odds_bookie(2,$fixtureID,$mID,$selID); echo selection_check($fixtureID,$mID,$selID,$session_user_id,"$odds") ?>
</button>

<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
<div class="modal-dialog modal-sm">
<div class="modal-content">
<div class="modal-header">
<button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>

<h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Odds Selection</h4>
</div>
<div class="modal-body">
<form role="form" name="add-odds" method="post" action="fix-2-form-proc.php" id="odds-form" >


<label for="exampleInputEmail1">Odds</label>
<input type="number" class="form-control col-md-3" name="odds" id="odds" step="any" value="">

<select name="bookieID" select class="form-control col-md-3" id="bookieID" required> <?php bookie_dropdown(0,$session_user_id) ?></select>
<select name="lID" select class="form-control col-md-3" required> <?php labels_dropdown(0,$session_user_id) ?></select>


<input type="hidden" name="eventID"     id="eventID"    value="<?php echo $fixtureID ?>">
<input type="hidden" name="mID"     id="mID"    value="<?php echo $mID ?>">
<input type="hidden" name="selID"   id="selID" value="<?php echo $selID ?>">
<input type="hidden" name="sID"     id="sID"    value="<?php echo 2 ?>">
<input type="hidden" name="fixID"   id="fixID" value="<?php echo $fixtureID ?>">

</div>
<div class="modal-footer">
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-info" name="add_odds">Add Odds</button>
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" name="add_sel">Select</button>
</div>
</form>
</div>
 </div>
</div>
<!-- End Modal -->


</div>
</div>
<?php
}?>
</div>
</div>
<?php
}?>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like that you are creating multiple modal divs with the same id again and again since your modal div is inside a while loop. Can you confirm if that is what you want?

It would be good if you check the generated HTML code and verify that your missing ids are actually coming correctly. From the code that you have pasted, it doesnt look like that bootstrap has anything to do with resetting those ids to '1'

Comment: thanks @pankaj I will move the hidden modal out of the loop and see if that fixes it. I'm so used to the PHP way of thinking...

Comment: It would be good, if you can explain what actually was the issue.